# Displaying a clickable button inside of a rendered cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to allow a user to click on a span using a fontawesome icon with a (click) action on it, however this seems to be discarded inside the cell, i have checked that manually placing one on the page works and so i know that the code will do what i expect.

How do i enable Angular to be rendered in the ag-grid?

This is linked to my popover issue i raised, but have not had success with.

Previously i have used:

```
  angularCompileRows: true,
```

in the grid options but this does not seem to work now.

```js
columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'ID', field: 'id' },
    { headerName: 'Name', field: 'customer.name' },
    { headerName: 'Email', field: 'customer.email' },
    { headerName: 'Actions', field: '', cellRenderer: this.actionCellRenderer }
  ];

.....


  actionCellRenderer(cell: any) {
    const view =
      '<span class="grid-action" (click)="openModal(content)"><a><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:white"></i></a></span>';
    const edit = '<span class="grid-action"><a (click)="clickbait()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" style="color:white"></i></a></span>';
    const del = '<span class="grid-action"><a (click)="open(content)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></span>';

    const start = '<div class="">';
    const end = '</div>';

    let result = start + view + edit + del + end;

    if (cell.value === null) {
      // result = start + cross + end;
    }
    return result;
  }

openModal(content: any) {
    console.log('openModal hit');
    this.modalService.open(AddEditCustomerComponent).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }
```

Any help appreciated.

PLUNKER: https://plnkr.co/edit/cUQaAGStLn0Hs3SS6acF

Comment: can you create a plunker please.

Comment: Plunker Added..

Comment: Why you dont create components for your actions buttons?

Comment: Can you show me an example where this resolves it at all? If using a component to display the cell render does this i will happily do it but if it results in exactly the same state why bother? the data is tied to this one specific page and has no need to be reused - thereby making the abstraction pointless unless for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

I too also could not get it work but as a workaround you can try the following

Get the row click event

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 450px;" class="ag-theme-material"
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (rowClicked)="onClick($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

and from the class of target event figure out which button was clicked

```
public onClick(e) {
    let button = e.event.target.getAttribute("class");
    console.log(button)
    switch(button) {
        case "fa fa-search":
            alert("clicked on search")
            return;
        case "fa fa-pencil-alt":
            alert("clicked on edit")
            return;
        case "fas fa-trash-alt":
            alert("clicked on delete")
            return;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/pRZVajU3VARrqniqxfID?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i want to try and get it working through only ag-grid if possible, but may use this as a backup

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [HTML DOM createElement() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Refer:[HTML DOM addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Refer:[What Does JavaScript Void(0) Mean?](https://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_void_0.cfm)

```
private actionCellRenderer(cell: any) {
    const eDiv = document.createElement('div');
    eDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="grid-action pointer"  href="javascript:void(0)"><a><i class="fa fa-search" style="color:black"></i></a></span>';
    eDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert('Your button is clickable');
    });
    return eDiv;
    }

    private createColumnDefs() {
        return [{
                headerName: "Full Name",
                field: "full_name"
            },
            {
                headerName: "actions",
                field: "full_name",
                cellRenderer: this.actionCellRenderer
            }
        ];
    }
```

Try using same for different iocns as a button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its not ideally what i wanted as i dont wish to go this far into using HTML editing on the controller but i tested it and it works so if i am stuck with it as the only answer i may use it. Thank you for your help.